# Rails3: how to use relational algebra to replace SQL-constructions like NOT and OUTER JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, outer-join, relational-algebra, arel

There are two models Post and Comment. I should get all posts, which have no comments with specific tag. How can I do this using new Rails 3 features such relational algebra ([arel](http://github.com/nkallen/arel)).

SQL-solution should be something like this:

```
SELECT     `posts`.* FROM       `posts` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `posts`.`id` = `comments`.`post_id`
WHERE    NOT (`comments`.`tag` = 'my_tag')
```

Comment: Does it support Minus? I can't see it anywhere on your link.

Comment: Arel: http://github.com/nkallen/arel
New Rails Active Record features: http://guides.rails.info/active_record_querying.html

It's common rails 3 querty interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'meta_where'
```

and then:

```
Post.includes(:comment).where(:comments => {:tag.not_eq => 'my_tag'})
```